# Xcode + Perforce: it frequently shows me the spinning wheel for no reason! What can i do?

Tags: xcode, version-control, perforce, performance

While working on an Xcode project i keep getting the spinning wheel while switching files, scrolling, searching, typing, debugging, removing breakpoints, switching back from another app or saving. It also happens before compiling but usually it just happens from time to time for no apparent reason.

This is the second time this started happening in a Xcode project and it's driving me nuts. It completely breaks my flow of work to have to wait for the spinning wheel to go away (2-5 seconds). What on earth could i possibly do to ...

- figure out what's causing the problem?
- resolve the problem?

---

**UPDATE:**
I have upgraded to Snow Leopard, installed Xcode 3.2 and in the meantime also upgraded the Perforce server to 2009.2. The problem is much less noticeable if not completely gone away.

---

More details:
When any project is small, everything is super-smooth with Xcode and Perforce. Two of my projects eventually had this spinning wheel problem after about 4 weeks of work. It only happened with those two projects so far. They consist of around 1000-1200 files in source control, most of them assets. The problem occurs even if i manually check out the whole project in Perforce. The problem is gone when i copy the project directory and work in the copy which is no longer under source control, or if i create a branch in Perforce and work in the branch (under source control).

One of these projects i shared with a colleague, and he had exactly the same issues on his Mac. We eventually switched to Subversion and the spinning-wheel issue immediately went away. Now that i've received an updated copy of the project and simply put it under Perforce as a new project, the problem also went away (so far it did not resurface). It leads me to think that it may be caused by a larger number of file revisions.

The server itself (version 2009.1) is on a different (Windows) machine on my LAN, so there's definetely no Internet lag involved. The complete repository is just 1 GB in size spread over a dozen projects or so.

I'm sorry if the question seems more like a support inquiry for Perforce. However i'm using the free version of Perforce so i'm not entitled to get support from them. I hope no one minds me asking here. I'm really bummed out by this. I don't want to have to create a new branch for the project each time the spinning wheel problem surfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that it is the XCode Perforce plugin that is causing the issues. I was about to suggest that you contact Perforce regarding the plugin, however the P4 integration is part of XCode which you means you need to talk to Apple support.

A quick google reveals that this is a known issue with XCode 3.1. A possible work-around is disabling the P4 integration and using AppleScript to check out files.

http://www.jaimerios.com/?p=136

HTH,

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i actually came across this post but didn't think it's part of the solution to my problem. In the meantime i did upgrade to Snow Leopard & Xcode 3.2 plus Perforce Server 2009.2 and so far the problem is much less noticeable, if at all.

Comment: can confirm, issue did not resurface on Snow Leopard with Xcode 3.2

Comment: That's good news - it looks like Apple fixed the issue with the XCode Perforce plugin.